okular doesn't automatically switch workspaces (24.04)
I have okular 24.05.2 installed on Ubuntu 24.04 (upgraded from 22.04)
Let's say that I open some_pdf.pdf by invoking
$ okular --unique some_pdf.pdf
This will give me a window with some_pdf.pdf showing up in okular.
Now I move this window to different workspace to the terminal.
Then I open the same pdf again by invoking the same command (some time later, or immediately after)
$ okular --unique some_pdf.pdf
Then I would expect no new window will open, but the focus of the window to shift to the workspace where okular is opened, and I should be able to browse the file afterwords. Or at least, it was a behaviour in the older version of Ubuntu. But instead nothing happens in the terminal, and goes to the next line with new prompt in the same workspace as the terminal.
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble


Lovely clear question Tom. Sorry I can't be of any actual help rn
